# User Control hide other HTML under declaration

Tags: asp.net

I have user contol under my project with next valid HTML code inside

```
<div class="myClass">
   <div>text bla bla</div>
</div>
```

I have CSS for `myClass`

```
.myClass
{
    display:none;
}
```

On aspx page I have next code

```
//my control
<uc:Spinner ID="Spinner1" runat="server" MinValue=0 MaxValue=10 />
//other HTML page
<div>
....
</div>
```

But when i load this page I expect to have visible all HTML code except html inside of `Spinner1` but all page data is hidden.
If I wrap contol to div tag like

```
<div>
  <uc:Spinner ID="Spinner1" runat="server" MinValue=0 MaxValue=10 />
</div>
```

Everything work fine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does your user control have a missing closing tag?

Comment: Your code isn't very clear, are you saying that your Spinner1 control is inside the myClass div or is it outside of it?  Could you post all HTML inside your body tags, that would make it easier.

Comment: Post the broken outputted html (not the aspx stuff).

Comment: Spinner1 this is control with HTML code <div class="myClass">
<div>text bla bla</div>
</div>

Comment: @cleric It is hard to understand, what the issue is, from your question. Could you post some more of your code? The rendered Html for instance.